# UIScrollview for load many view in ipad

Tags: ipad, uiscrollview

I want to implement scroll view for viewing event for day:

Day1----Day2---....--- Day90 
Event11-Event21-....---Event901 
Event12-Event22-....---Event902 
Event13-Event23-....---Event903 
Event14-Event24-....---Event904 
Event15-Event25-....---Event905 
.............................

(About 60~90 rows)

But when scroll up/down/left right, it is not smooth.
Especially, when viewing for visible event, GUI seems to be locked.
I wonder how Amazon Windowshop for ipad can do that. What technique for the view in Amazon Windowshop for ipad?

Thanks

Comment: Hello and welcome Stack Overflow. Please take a few minutes to read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Please add appropriate tags for the libraries you are using and for which target platform you are developing.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that because Amazon Windowshop app may not (mostly) using `UIScrollView` for this, instead they may use `UICollectionView` (or kind of reusable stuff), also with `UIScrollView` all request of your data will be added at once and not one by one.

IMHO, you shouldn't use `UIScrollView` for this.

Comment: With UICollectionView, we have to fix width for UICollectionView as creen size. But Amazon Windowshop for iPad, it maybe NOT fix width.

Comment: That's not true, the width of cell size depends on UI need of your app.

Comment: Indeed, I want a view to scroll 2 directions (both vertical and horizontal). But UICollectionView can only scroll vertical or horizontal.